# ctrl-a increasing 017 to 020

Tags: key-bindings

Having the cursor on a `017` and doing a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> increases it to `020`, when I would have expected `018`. Is this a bug (vim 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04) or why would one want this?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about ctrl+A and ctrl+X.

Answer (score 8):

This is vim expecting `017` to be octal and doing the sensible thing for an octal number (`017` = 8+7 = 15; `020` = 2*8 = 16).

To tell vim you don't use octal numbers, `set nrformats-=octal`. More at `:help 'nrformats'` and `:help CTRL-A`.

Comment: Since so many people today think this a mistake, it is worth pointing out that vim follows this editing convention because numerous programming languages also do for their numeric constants.. including C, javascript, perl, ruby, and python2.

Comment: Also worth noting that [defaults.vim disables octal in nrformats](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/defaults.vim#L60), so you'll get that setting correct if you don't have a vimrc file or if you [source it explicitly](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim).

Comment: @Mass Note that they're trying to deprecate 0-prefixed octal constants in JavaScript.